# Alternative for gets in C

Tags: c, gets

I need help optimizing the code below, it's been a while since I coded in C and something has changed since then.

> Write a program that asks for a name that compares to those that it
> has as elements of a character array and greets or announces that she
> is "stranger".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char who[110];
        char names []="Sam John Tom Sophia Jane Mary ";
        printf("Enter a name: ");
        gets(who);
        char *ptr=strstr(names, who);
    
        printf("\n%s\n",who);
    
        if (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf("We know '%s'\n", who);
            printf("Hello %s", who);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("We don`t know '%s'\n", who);
            printf("%s is a STRANGER!!", who);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%s", c_string_char_array)` works perfectly, if you search about it, you can add lengths and other juicy things in it.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT Yes, `scanf ("%s", ...)` without a _width_ is legal and worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Comment: You could use [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) - if that is allowed to you

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard function `fgets`. For example

```
fgets( who, sizeof( who ), stdin );
who[ strcspn( who, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

The function can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string that you need to remove before using the function `strstr`.

Alternatively you can use function `scanf` the following way

```
scanf( "%109[^\n]", s );
```

In this case the new line character `'\n'` will not be read in the character array.

if you need to enter only one word then you can use `scanf` like

```
scanf( "%109s", who );
```

As for your approach then in general it is incorrect. For example the user can enter the word "Jo" and the function `strstr` will return a non-null pointer.

It is better to use an array of pointers to string literals like

```
const char *names[] = { "Sam", "John", "Tom", "Sophia", "Jane", "Mary" };
```

and then in a loop to check whether the entered string coincides with a string literal in the array.

For example

```
const char *names[] = { "Sam", "John", "Tom", "Sophia", "Jane", "Mary" };
const size_t N = sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names );

//...
size_t i = 0;

while ( i != N && strcmp( names[i], who ) != 0 ) i++;

if ( i != N )
{
    printf("We know '%s'\n", who);
    printf("Hello %s", who);
}
else
{
    printf("We don`t know '%s'\n", who);
    printf("%s is a STRANGER!!", who);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `scanf(" %109[^\n]", who)` as a replacement for `gets()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane No, it is not a replacement. In fact he needs to enter one word.:)

Comment: It's a closer replacement (as the question title) for `gets()` than `%s` which stops at the first space, if any. There isn't an exact replacement unless you read the newline too.

Comment: `scanf( "%109[^\n]", s );` also has a problem if input begins with `'\n'`. Then `s` remains unwritten.  `s` does not become `""`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The same problem can be and with fgets if the buffer contain the new line character. It is not a problem of the function. It is a problem of the user.